# Why does the object my C++ point to lose its values in my factory pattern?

Tags: c++, pointers, factory-pattern

I'm trying to use a factory pattern to create different types of "State" objects.  The objects are returned with a pointer (State*) but shortly after the objects are created, the values they point to disappear (go to NULL or reset to boolean "true").

The code directly below is where it goes awry, but below that is a complete code sample that compiles and runs.  Additionally, I've posted pictures of the debugger values before and after the usleep() command.

I feel like it may have something to do with scope and the garbage collector, but I'm not a C++ expert by any stretch of the imagination.  I would have thought my pointer would have kept my referenced object alive.

```
// relevant code

        void execute(){
            // Calling the constructor directly as an example
            State directState = State("temp", false, false, false);
            // Using factory pattern to create a state.  Just creating the "default" state as an example
            State * factoryState = StateFactory::getDefaultState();
            // factoryState -> name is "Reading" in the debugger, but when I try to print it out, it's gone
            // Grab the names for easy reference
            const char * dName = directState.name;
            const char * fName = factoryState -> name;
            usleep(1000000 / 100);
            // factoryState -> name .... it's vanished?
            usleep(1000000 / 100);
            // TODO we would run the factoryState -> execute() function here
        }
```

```
// Complete code example

#include <iostream>
#include <zconf.h>

// Main generic "State" class
class State {
    public:
        const char * name;
        bool isReadable;
        bool isExecuting;
        bool isFinished;

        State(const char name[], bool isReadable, bool isExecuting, bool isFinished){
            this -> name = name;
            this -> isReadable = isReadable;
            this -> isExecuting = isExecuting;
            this -> isFinished = isFinished;
        }
};

// An inherited class.  There will be lots of these eventually
class StateReading: public State { ;
    public:
        StateReading():State((const char *)"Reading", true, false, false) {}
};

// Factory method that will create lots of the different states
// note that it will be returning a pointer to a "State" object
class StateFactory {
    public:
        static State* getDefaultState(){
            StateReading defaultState = StateReading();
            State* state = &defaultState;
            return state;
        }
};

// Runs the various "States" in a template pattern
class StateExecutor {
    public:
        State * state;

        StateExecutor(){
            StateReading stateReading = StateReading();
            state = &stateReading;
        }

        void execute(){
            // Calling the constructor directly as an example
            State directState = State("temp", false, false, false);
            // Using factory pattern to create a state.  Just creating the "default" state as an example
            State * factoryState = StateFactory::getDefaultState();
            // factoryState -> name is "Reading" in the debugger, but when I try to print it out, it's gone
            // Grab the names for easy reference
            const char * dName = directState.name;
            const char * fName = factoryState -> name;
            usleep(1000000 / 100);
            // factoryState -> name .... it's disappeard?
            usleep(1000000 / 100);
            // TODO we would run the factoryState -> execute() function here
        }
};


// The actual
void loop(StateExecutor stateExecutor) {
    // Run the "execute" function of whatever the current state is
    // The stateExecutor actually runs the state
    stateExecutor.execute();
    // Slow the loop down a little.  Just for effect
    usleep(1000000 / 100);
}

// Simple program to recreate an event loop
int main() {

    try {
        StateExecutor stateExecutor = StateExecutor();
        int count = 0;
        do {
            loop(stateExecutor);
            count++;
            // Arbitrarily break out of the loop after 100 events.
        } while(count < 100);
    }  catch (std::exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Here are the values directly after the factory created them.  All looks good.

[image: Before usleep]

Gah!  I called usleep() and the factoryState's name field is gone and the bools have reverted to true (cout does this as well).  Black magic!

[image: After usleep]

Comment: C++ doesn't have a garbage collector. `StateReading defaultState` created in `getDefaultState()` is destroyed when the function exits, saving a pointer to it doesn't change that.

Comment: Why all the raw pointers? And, seriously, *sleep* calls? Why not `std::string`? And if you are using sleeps/delays for synchronization you are *doing it wrong*. Also, learn about *scopes* and *object lifetimes*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is a simple code example to demonstrate a problem.  We're not launching rockets here.

Comment: @Will The problem you are having is that you don't seem to understand object lifetimes in C++. Rockets or no rockets doesn't matter - your code is still broken / has Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Launching rockets or not, proper understand and good code is still  important.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I definitely don't understand! lol. This is about C++ day 3 for me. No sarcasm included, thank you for the help.

Comment: This code is being translated into Arduino code and std::string (from my very limited knowledge) is not accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
    static State* getDefaultState(){
        StateReading defaultState = StateReading();
        State* state = &defaultState;
        return state;
    }
```

You return a pointer to `defaultState`. This state however is destroyed when the function returns. Using this pointer later is undefined behavior. You can declare `defaultState` as `static`, though i would rather make it a static member.